# Does swipe gestures work on a object in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, swipe

I've found this tutorial about working with touch gestures in AS3:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/

But doing the same that it says doesnt work for me: i cant get the swipe gesture work on an object. It seems only work if i apply the listener on the stage instead. However the flash help says that does apply to objects! Anyone could get this work?

If i apply it to an object does nothing but if apply it to the stage the same code works! What i am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your object is to small to detect the swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a throw behavior, maybe `TOUCH_BEGIN`, `TOUCH_MOVE`, and `TOUCH_END` will help.

I suggest to read this article too:
 http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html